# How do I set the Windows execution level to ask user for administrator privileges for a Rust program?

Tags: windows, rust

I'm writing a Windows CLI app and I need to run it as administrator. In C# I would add this line to app.manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

How I do that in Rust?

Comment: This isn't a broad question. This is a very specific, narrow question.

Comment: Sorry @SebastianRedl but "How do I do X" with no effort is not a good question.

Comment: @hellow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x - I don't know what side of this debate you fall on, but this question isn't too broad, so it's not closable. You may downvote it if you feel more research effort should have been made (or shown to have been made), but voting as too broad is wrong. (As an aside, googling "how do I add manifest to rust application" brings up the RFC thread I linked, which might help, but would definitely be intimidating to a newcomer).

Comment: the question is specific, I did google it and try to find an answer... I also found that link, but did not find solution reading it .. I'm very new to rust and I really do not see the problem with asking here for additional help .. now I'm prevented by stackoverflow to ask additional questions and get help, but ok

Comment: @TomislavNekic but why didn't you include the RFC in your question then? That would have showed us/me that you did deal with the question and not blindly run to SO.

Comment: sorry, I was not aware that I need to prove that I tried to solve it.

Comment: @hellow I think this question & answer is still useful and shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open RFC #721 for manifest support in Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/721).

Aside from discussing ways to add native support, the posts contain links to various workarounds using linker switches or other tools. There is currently no nice way to pass linker switches; you have to put a `rustflags` option into a [Cargo config file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) and pass the arguments through to `rustc` like this: `["-C", "link-args=/exoticlinkerswitch"]`. This is obviously not very portable.

For tools, you can [use `mt.exe` from the Windows SDK to add a manifest to your program after it has been compiled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Note that Cargo does not currently have a way to execute post-build steps automatically. However, there is a Cargo extension, `cargo-make` that supports such build processes. You can install it via `cargo install cargo-make`.

Answer (score 16):

Too late, but answering anyway. :-)

Please take a look at the [`winres`](https://crates.io/crates/winres) library. It contains the following example:

> The following manifest will brand the exe as requesting administrator
>   privileges. Thus, everytime it is executed, a Windows UAC dialog will
>   appear.
>
> ```
> let mut res = winres::WindowsResource::new();
> res.set_manifest(r#"
> <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
> <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>     <security>
>         <requestedPrivileges>
>             <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
>         </requestedPrivileges>
>     </security>
> </trustInfo>
> </assembly>
> "#);
> ```

The full example is documented and available [here](https://docs.rs/winres/0.1.11/winres/struct.WindowsResource.html#example-1).

I have been using this library in a project that contains an icon and requires admin privileges, its `build.rs` using `winres` is hosted [here](https://github.com/risoflora/fiscalidade_server/blob/e0a4e1b7a75ed0e172c48f88282d3bc2b4c15e6d/build.rs). See the generated executable: [image]

HTH

Comment: I appreciate modern answers to retro questions, thanks.