# Launch process that asks for elevation (UAC)

Tags: rust

This is my code so far

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    ...
    Command::new(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI Afterburner\MSIAfterburner.exe")
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();
    ...
}
```

And I got this error:

```
{ code: 740, message: "The requested operation requires elevation." }
```

I found [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-a-new-process-be-launched-that-prompts-uac/11326) which is probably what I need but I don't know how to do it 
If anyone could make an example on how to do it that would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main(){
    Command::new("cmd.exe")
    .args(["/C",r"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI Afterburner\MSIAfterburner.exe"])
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();
}
```

Kinda ugly but works.

Comment: This is bad because the cmd appears on the screen

Comment: you can pass a flag that removes the cmd on the screen. You can find the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750113/how-do-i-hide-the-console-window-for-a-process-started-with-stdprocesscomman . Additionally this workaround might not even be required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846395/how-do-i-set-the-windows-execution-level-to-ask-user-for-administrator-privilege